# Proof of Hadamard's theorem in book of Do Carmo

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

I'm currently reading the book of Do Carmo but I don't understand something in the proof of Hadamard's theorem. He first proves two lemmas which I understand completely but in the actual proof of the theorem, he states that $\exp_p : T_pM \to M$ is a local isometry because it is a local diffeomorphism. However, he then says that the induced metric on $T_pM$ is complete because the geodesics that pass through the origin are straight lines. I don't really see how this follows and I was wondering if someone could help me understand.

Comment: Do you know what is the metric on $T_p M$?

Comment: So given a $v \in T_pM$ then for $\alpha, \beta \in T_v(T_pM)$ we have the metric
$$ \langle \alpha, \beta \rangle_v = \big\langle (d\exp_p)_v(\alpha), (d\exp_p)_v(\beta)\big\rangle_{\exp_p(v)}$$ where the latter is just the metric on $M$ at $\exp_p(v)$, which is well defined because $\exp_p$ is a local diffeomorphism, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are using the following fact:

If $F: (M, g)\to (N, h)$ is a local isometry, then a curve $\gamma$ in $M$ is a geodesic if and only if $F(\gamma)$ is a geodesic in $N$.

In our situation, the straight lines $\{ tw : t\in \mathbb R\}$ passing through the origin is a geodesic in $T_pM$ with the induced metric, since $\exp_p(tw)$ is a geodesic in $M$. Then for all $w\in T_pM \cong T_0(T_pM)$, then geodesic passing through $0$ with vector $w$ is just $t\mapsto tw$ and thus is defined for all $t\in \mathbb R$. Thus implies that $T_pM$ is complete with the induced metric.